# CUDA: Stack vector in different thread to a 1d vector

Tags: vector, cuda, gpu, thrust

I have a thrust vector for each thread in CUDA, and I want to stack vectors by orders (vector in thread 0, vector in thread 1,.... and vector in thread n) to create a 1d vector and send back to CPU. Is there a good way to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your current approach? How would you do it in plain C without CUDA?

Comment: What do you mean by "a thrust vector for each thread"? As you [cannot](https://godbolt.org/z/GMMj7s4a9) use `thrust::device_vector` in device code/kernels, that question doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most performant way to store items from several threads into a single vector will be thread-interleaved.  Suppose each of 4 threads (t0-t3) has 4 elements to store (e0-e3).  The final storage pattern which will be most efficient will be:

```
t0e0 t1e0 t2e0 t3e0 t0e1 t1e1 t2e1 t3e1 t0e2 t1e2 t2e2 t3e2 t0e3 t1e3 t2e3 t3e3
```

The code to do that would look like this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
const int nt = 4;
const int ne = 4;
template <typename T>
__global__ void k(T *d){

  T e0 = threadIdx.x+10;
  T e1 = threadIdx.x+20;
  T e2 = threadIdx.x+30;
  T e3 = threadIdx.x+40;
  d[threadIdx.x]      = e0;
  d[threadIdx.x+nt]   = e1;
  d[threadIdx.x+2*nt] = e2;
  d[threadIdx.x+3*nt] = e3;
}

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<int> d(ne*nt);
  k<<<1,nt>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d.data()));
}
```

In your question it seems that you want this order:

```
t0e0 t0e1 t0e2 t0e3 t1e0 t1e1 t1e2 t1e3 t2e0 t2e1 t2e2 t2e3 t3e0 t3e1 t3e2 t3e3
```

That storage pattern will generally be less efficient, but you could achieve it like this:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
const int nt = 4;
const int ne = 4;
template <typename T>
__global__ void k(T *d){

  T e0 = threadIdx.x+10;
  T e1 = threadIdx.x+20;
  T e2 = threadIdx.x+30;
  T e3 = threadIdx.x+40;
  d[threadIdx.x*nt]    = e0;
  d[threadIdx.x*nt+1]  = e1;
  d[threadIdx.x*nt+2]  = e2;
  d[threadIdx.x*nt+3]  = e3;
}

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<int> d(ne*nt);
  k<<<1,nt>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d.data()));
}
```

The storage efficiency difference in these two cases is the difference between uncoalesced and coalesced behavior, which is covered in numerous questions here on the `cuda` SO tag, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281857/cuda-efficient-memory-access).